# How to add an integer to an existing dataframe of different column length in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, integer

Sorry if this question has been asked already. I am new to R.

I currently have a dataframe with 1 column. I am trying to build this dataframe with different integers I have.

```
Apeaks
1
6
5
```

I have the following integers

```
Bpeaks = 2 1 6 12 10 5 8
Cpeaks = 2 1
Dpeaks = 4 1 0 9 20 4 18 11 9 6
```

I am trying to add the integer (list of integers?) Bpeaks to the dataframe Apeaks as a column. At the same time, the Apeaks column would only have 3 values while the Bpeaks column will have 7 values. I am trying to assign the value of 0 for each row of Apeaks for the extra # of rows as Bpeaks.

This is what I'm hoping for my result

```
Apeaks Bpeaks
1      2
6      1
5      6
0      12
0      10
0      5
0      8
```

In addition, when I add a column of shorter value, the rows will automatically be assigned as 0. For example

```
Cpeaks = 2 1


Apeaks Bpeaks Cpeaks
1      2      2
6      1      1
5      6      0
0      12     0
0      10     0
0      5      0
0      8      0
```

And when I add another column of longer length, all the existing columns add a value of 0 for each extra row. For example

```
Dpeaks = 4 1 0 9 20 4 18 11 9 6

Apeaks Bpeaks Cpeaks Dpeaks
1      2      2      4
6      1      1      1
5      6      0      0
0      12     0      9
0      10     0      20
0      5      0      4
0      8      0      18
0      0      0      11
0      0      0      9
0      0      0      6
```

Is there any way to do this (code would be very helpful)? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to add new columns :

```
add_Data <- function(df, vec) {
   colname <- deparse(substitute(vec))
   new_row <- max(nrow(df), length(vec))
   new_df <- df[1:new_row, ,drop = FALSE]
   new_df[colname] <- c(vec, rep(NA, new_row - length(vec)))
   new_df[is.na(new_df)] <- 0
   rownames(new_df) <- NULL
   new_df
}

Bpeaks = c(2, 1, 6, 12, 10, 5, 8)
Cpeaks = c(2, 1)
Dpeaks = c(4, 1, 0, 9, 20, 4, 18, 11, 9, 6)

df <- add_Data(df, Bpeaks)
df

#  Apeaks Bpeaks
#1      1      2
#2      6      1
#3      5      6
#4      0     12
#5      0     10
#6      0      5
#7      0      8
```

Adding `Cpeaks`

```
df <- add_Data(df, Cpeaks)
df
#  Apeaks Bpeaks Cpeaks
#1      1      2      2
#2      6      1      1
#3      5      6      0
#4      0     12      0
#5      0     10      0
#6      0      5      0
#7      0      8      0
```

Adding `Dpeaks` :

```
df <- add_Data(df, Dpeaks)
df
#   Apeaks Bpeaks Cpeaks Dpeaks
#1       1      2      2      4
#2       6      1      1      1
#3       5      6      0      0
#4       0     12      0      9
#5       0     10      0     20
#6       0      5      0      4
#7       0      8      0     18
#8       0      0      0     11
#9       0      0      0      9
#10      0      0      0      6
```

**data**

We started off with this dataframe :

```
df <- structure(list(Apeaks = c(1L, 6L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! One additional question- How can I change the names of the columns based on a variable I already have created? Is it possible to do this within the function? For example, ```title <- "Sample name here"``` and everytime I add in the new column using the add_Data function, instead of the column name being "Bpeaks" it will be the title. Thank you!

Comment: @tshast2 Add one more variable in the function `add_Data <- function(df, vec, colname) {.....` and remove the first line in the function of `deparse(substitute`. you can then call the function as `add_Data(df, Dpeaks, title)`

Comment: is it possible to add integers of the same column name to the same column? For example, instead of another "Dpeaks" adding an additional column called "Dpeaks" to the dataframe, it adds to the already existing column called "Dpeaks".

Comment: @tshast2 I added an answer to your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763135/is-there-a-way-to-edit-this-function-to-add-numbers-to-the-same-column/

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that allows for adding multiple vectors at once. It also includes an option to rename the variable where the vector is going to be added.

```
add_data <- function(df, ..., names = NULL) {
  l <- list(...)
  if (!is.null(names)) { if (length(names) != length(l)) stop("wrong number of names") }
  if (is.null(names)) names <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
  l <- c(c(df), setNames(l, names))
  out <- data.frame(lapply(l, `length<-`, max(lengths(l))))
  replace(out, is.na(out), 0)
}
```

Here we're adding `Bpeaks` and `Cpeaks`, keeping the names of the objects.

```
add_data(df, Bpeaks, Cpeaks)
#   Apeaks Bpeaks Cpeaks
# 1      1      2      2
# 2      6      1      1
# 3      5      6      0
# 4      0     12      0
# 5      0     10      0
# 6      0      5      0
# 7      0      8      0
```

Here, we're adding `Cpeaks` and `Dpeaks`, but renaming them to "C", and "D".

```
add_data(df, Cpeaks, Dpeaks, names = c("C", "D"))
#    Apeaks C  D
# 1       1 2  4
# 2       6 1  1
# 3       5 0  0
# 4       0 0  9
# 5       0 0 20
# 6       0 0  4
# 7       0 0 18
# 8       0 0 11
# 9       0 0  9
# 10      0 0  6
```

Comment: @27ϕ9, Thanks. I had done that when manually trying a few things but forgot to add it back in the function. Guess I shouldn't answer questions on SO at midnight ;-)