# Is it possible to create a R function for my code?

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to create a function for my code below? I have multiple csv files that I'm running this exact code on, but it has been tiring using this same code over and over to do the same thing (and has made my script very long). Here is my code-

```
#define a function "add_peaks" to transpose peak values into summary table
add_peaks <- function(df, vec, colname) {
  if(colname %in% names(df)) vec <- c(df[[colname]], vec)
  new_row <- max(nrow(df), length(vec))
  new_df <- df[1:new_row, ,drop = FALSE]
  new_df[colname] <- c(vec, rep(NA, new_row - length(vec)))
  new_df[is.na(new_df)] <- 0
  rownames(new_df) <- NULL
  new_df
}

#####INPUT#####
#Read in appropriate experiment number
#Remove first 2 columns
#Rename first column to "mintime" and convert to minutes
#Normalize raw fluorescence values

flowdata <- read_csv("####.csv")                                      ####CHANGE EXP NUMBER
title <- "CONDITION HERE"                                             ####CHANGE CONDITION"
flowdata <- flowdata[, -c(1:2)]  %>%
  rename(mintime = 1) %>%
  transform(mintime = mintime / 60)
flowdata[,-1] <- data.frame(lapply(flowdata[,-1], function(X) X/X[1]))

#Exclude values up to 5 minutes
#Determine number of peaks per cell
#Add number of peaks per cell to summary table
flowdata_cut <- flowdata[which(flowdata$mintime>=5),]
peak_info <- lapply(flowdata_cut[,-1], findpeaks, threshold=2)
numberpeak <- unlist(lapply(peak_info, nrow))
summarypeaks <- add_peaks(summarypeaks, numberpeak, title)

#Prepare data for line graph
melted <- melt(flowdata, id.vars="mintime")

#####CREATE GRAPH#####
#Plot graph
ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=mintime, y=value, group=variable)) + 
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3, 12), breaks = seq(3, 12, by = 3)) +
  labs(y="Fluo-4 fluorescence (F/F0)", x = "Time (min)") +            
  ggtitle(title) +                                   
  theme_bw() +
  
  # remove elements we don't need
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.background = element_blank()) 
  
 
#####SAVE GRAPH##### 
#Save line graph as .png file
ggsave(filename = "####_Line_Graph.png",                              ####CHANGE EXP NUMBER
       width = 8, height = 4)
```

Please let me know if it is possible (code is appreciated), even if it is part of it only. Obviously I am new to coding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your code, extracted into a function that takes 2 arguments - the experiment number (`exp`) and the condition (`cond`).

```
my_function <- function(exp, cond) {
    
    #Read in appropriate experiment number
    #Remove first 2 columns
    #Rename first column to "mintime" and convert to minutes
    #Normalize raw fluorescence values

    flowdata <- read_csv(paste0(exp, ".csv"))                                  
    title <- cond                                            
    flowdata <- flowdata[, -c(1:2)] %>%
        rename(mintime = 1) %>%
        transform(mintime = mintime / 60)
    flowdata[,-1] <- data.frame(lapply(flowdata[,-1], function(X) X/X[1]))
    
    #Exclude values up to 5 minutes
    #Determine number of peaks per cell
    #Add number of peaks per cell to summary table
    flowdata_cut <- flowdata[which(flowdata$mintime>=5),]
    peak_info <- lapply(flowdata_cut[,-1], findpeaks, threshold=2)
    numberpeak <- unlist(lapply(peak_info, nrow))
    summarypeaks <- add_peaks(summarypeaks, numberpeak, title)
    
    #Prepare data for line graph
    melted <- melt(flowdata, id.vars="mintime")
    
    #####CREATE GRAPH#####
    #Plot graph
    ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=mintime, y=value, group=variable)) + 
        geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3, 12), breaks = seq(3, 12, by = 3)) +
        labs(y="Fluo-4 fluorescence (F/F0)", x = "Time (min)") +            
        ggtitle(title) +                                   
        theme_bw() +
        
        # remove elements we don't need
        theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
              panel.border = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
              panel.background = element_blank()) 
    
    
    #####SAVE GRAPH##### 
    #Save line graph as .png file
    ggsave(filename = paste0(exp, "_Line_Graph.png"), width = 8, height = 4)
   
    # Return
    return(summarypeaks)

}
```

If you have experiment number 005 and condition "test", call the function like so, assigning the result to replace the old value of `summarypeaks`:

```
summarypeaks <- my_function(005, "test")
```

Comment: Thank you! Only issue I'm having is I have a function called add_peaks in the code that seems to not be working now. Here is my function ``` #define a function "add_peaks" to transpose peak values into summary table
add_peaks <- function(df, vec, colname) {
  if(colname %in% names(df)) vec <- c(df[[colname]], vec)
  new_row <- max(nrow(df), length(vec))
  new_df <- df[1:new_row, ,drop = FALSE]
  new_df[colname] <- c(vec, rep(NA, new_row - length(vec)))
  new_df[is.na(new_df)] <- 0
  rownames(new_df) <- NULL
  new_df
} ``` Is it possible to have a function within a function?

Comment: Could I see the error message you're getting? I'm assuming the error comes from the line `summarypeaks <- add_peaks(summarypeaks, numberpeak, title)`, since the object `summarypeaks` hasn't been declared yet when you're trying to use it inside `add_peaks`... Might you have meant to pass a different data frame to `add_peaks`?

Comment: Actually, I am not getting an error message (or any message). My summarypeaks dataframe was defined earlier in the code- when I ran my first csv file without the function- `flowdata_cut <- flowdata[which(flowdata$mintime>=5),]
peak_info <- lapply(flowdata_cut[,-1], findpeaks, threshold=2)
numberpeak <- unlist(lapply(peak_info, nrow))
summarypeaks <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(numberpeak), nrow=length(numberpeak), byrow=T))
colnames(summarypeaks) <- c(title) ` The summarypeaks file isn't adding new integers when I run the function

Comment: If it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763135/is-there-a-way-to-edit-this-function-to-add-numbers-to-the-same-column/ describes what add_peaks is doing

Comment: I see what you mean. The issue seems to be related to scope - the `summarypeaks` data frame outside the function and the summary data frame inside the function are different, so if we add new stuff to the inside one, it won't show up in the outside one. To get the updated version from within the function for use on the outside, we need to return it and assign the result to replace the old value. See my updated answer.

Comment: To illustrate the issue you ran into on a smaller scale, try running the following toy code: `a <- 2 ; fun <- function() { a <- a + 1 ; paste("a inside:", a) } ; fun() ; paste("a outside:", a)`. The value of `a` from the outside got used inside the function and incremented, becoming 3, but the updates made inside the function cannot be seen on the outside - `a` remains 2 on the outside.

Comment: The updated function worked perfectly! Thank you for all your help.